# How to Convert String into ArrayCollection in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Actually my Flex Application ..Sample code

```
private var selectedDays:String = null;
            protected function selectRepeatedDays(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                selectedDays = new String();
                if(MON.selected==true)
                {
                    selectedDays += "MONDAY,";
                    Alert.show("Monday  :"+selectedDays);
                }
                if(TUE.selected==true)
                {
                    selectedDays +=  "TUESDAY,";
                }
                if(WED.selected==true)
                {
                    selectedDays += "WEDNESDAY,";
                    Alert.show("Monday  :"+selectedDays);
                }
                if(THU.selected==true)
                {
                    selectedDays += "THURSDAY,";
                }

}
var arr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
arr = selectedDays.substr(0, selectedDays.length-1).toString();

Alert.show(arr.lenth)
```

But it is not convert... the Alert Statement Not Prompt ..
So How to Convert This String into ArrayCollection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method [split](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29) to convert the String to Array:

```
var array:Array = selectedDays.split(",");
```

Then (if needed yet) add each item of Array to the ArrayCollection:

```
var arr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
for each (var str:String in array) {
    arr.addItem(str);
}
```

Comment: var arr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(array);

Answer (score 1):

use below code snippet to convert String to ArrayCollection

1. Convert String to Array using split method

   ```
   var array:Array = selectedDays.split(",");
   ```
2. Convert Array to ArrayCollection

   ```
   var selectedDaysArr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(array);
   ```